# The relation $S(u^1_i)u^j_1 = q^{-1}u^j_1S(u^1_i)$

Tags: hopf-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra

In the Hopf algebra $SL_q(N)$, it can be shown, using direct calculations, that $S(u^1_i)u^j_1 = q^{-1}u^j_1S(u^1_i)$. Can anyone see a more elegant way of establishing this?

Moreover, does anyone know of a similar relation in the more general case of $S(u^1_r)u^i_j$?

Edit (referneces): By $SL_q(N)$ I mean the quantized coordinate algebra (not the quantized enveloping algebra). I am using the conventions of Klimyk and Schmudgen, Chpt 4 for the N=2 case, or Chpt 9 for the general case.

Comment: Could you add a reference for this model of quantum groups?  It is not exactly the same as the usual $U_q(sl(N))$.  And your question depends on precise conventions.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. It's not the quantum enveloping algebra, it's the quantised coordinate algebra. I've added the references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a reasonably known result. That $S(u^1_i)u^j_1 = q^{-1}u^j_1S(u^1_i)$,  was originally proven (to the best of my knowdledge) in FRT's '89 paper "Quantum Groups and Lie Algebras" - the paper is in Russian though. The only English write up of the proof that I known is in Theorem 1 of Vainermann and Podkolzin's '99 [paper](http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3AH1PD0VCip6MJ%3Aciteseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download%253Fdoi%253D10.1.1.145.4800%2526rep%253Drep1%2526type%253Dpdf+quantum+Stieffel+manifold&hl=ga&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESj18ZxTGm6y0t_mQ4GrrzMrIRnK_9B_Oynw9gDehj-Z6NEiQHuWDEhtgQxsfu8rEmlZnp1b-O6GGfNhD5mEJQK15EUlHs9WiQGsbIZJp61PjBfrTgJtrEnovntBZZBh_OmYcjXk&sig=AHIEtbRxdwbZXWeC01h1RfkqMawEnDG86w) on Quantum Stiefel Manifolds. It gives a general comm rel for $[S(u^i_j),u^r_s]$, for the general $N$ case, using just the $R$-matrix construction of the $SU_q(N)$. I am sure there are other versions around somewhere though.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, I would use the dual pairing with $U_q(\mathfrak{sl}_N)$.  The $u_i^j$'s are defined to be matrix coefficients of the vector representation of $U_q(\mathfrak{sl}_N)$ with respect to some distinguished basis, usually a basis of weight vectors.  There are unfortunately a lot of different conventions in use.  My standard reference is Klimyk and Schmudgen.  See, for example, Theorem 19 of Chapter 9 of their book.  It states:

There is a unique dual pairing $( , )$ of Hopf algebras between $U_q^{ext}(\mathfrak{sl}_N)$ and $\mathcal{O}(SL_q(N))$ such that $(f, u^k_l) = t_{kl}(f)$ for all $f \in U_q^{ext}  (\mathfrak{sl}_{N})$.

Here $((t_{kl}(f))$ is the matrix for $f$ in the vector representation.  OK, this theorem is a little bogus in the sense that it is more of a definition.  But the point is that $\mathcal{O}(SL_q(N))$ is generated by the matrix coefficients of all finite-dimensional irreducible representations of $U_q^{ext}  (\mathfrak{sl}_{N})$, and these separate points of $U_q^{ext}  (\mathfrak{sl}_{N})$, so the pairing is nondegenerate.

So, to show that your two guys are equal, just show that they pair the same way with $U_q^{ext}  (\mathfrak{sl}_{N})$.  Since it is a pairing of Hopf algebras, you just need to check on the generators $E_i, F_i, K_\lambda$.  This just requires you to have a handle on the vector representation.  In my opinion this is much cleaner than doing the calculations directly.

Comment: Great, this is just what I was looking for. Just one thing though, I don'e see why the fact that its a Hopf algebra pairing implies that I only need to check it on the generators. How do I get the value of $< x,E^2> = <x_{(1)},E> < x_{(2)}, E >$ from the pairings of $x$ with the generators?

Comment: ... take the example, for $N=2$, of $<b^2,K>=<b^2,E>=<b^2,F>=0$, while of course $b^2 \neq 0$.

Comment: Yeah, you're right.  Hmmm... not quite sure how to resolve that.  I guess the generators aren't enough.  So perhaps this doesn't work after all.  My bad.